# Is there a way to upload a json file to an azure blob without saving the json data to a local file?

Tags: python, json, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am making a python based webapp that uses jsons to store information for different accounts. I am not able to temporarily save the json data to a local file and then upload it to a blob. Is there a way to remove that step and just upload the json data directley as a file in a blob?

This is how you normally upload a file

```py
with open(upload_file_path, "rb") as data:
    blob_client.upload_blob(data)
```

Is there something like `blob_client.upload_blob(<json object>)` that works?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something like blob_client.upload_blob(<json object>) that
> works?

Yes. If you look at the documentation for [`upload_blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobclient-upload-blob), you will notice that the `data` parameter can be of `AnyStr`, `Iterable` or `IO` type.

What you could do is serialize the JSON object as string using `json.dumps()` and pass that as data to the upload_blob method.